# How to install Drupal 7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 7, installation

I'm in the process to move the development on Ubuntu 14.04.

At the beginning everything seemed to work fine but quickly I discovered it was not.

Installing new modules, by UI, Drupal stops without (displaying) any error and shows a blank page. After that, the site works undisturbed. You can go back and continue on other tasks.

After many attempts to log the error without success, I run few test with [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) discovering that the code stops, with no reason, in `system.tar.inc`, when preparing to `untar` the package. Really weird.

Tried with fresh install of Drupal 7.28: the same.

Now I don't know how to go on. Main suspect is PHP 5.5.9, but before starting a new adventure with PHP versions, I'd like to hear you. What should I try first?

---

No way.
Reinstalled starting from a new VirtualBox, Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 7.28.
Same story, all is working but stops when I try to install a new module (without errors).

I took note of every piece i installed and can't find a reason why.

### apache

```
    apt-get install apache2
```

- in global section of /etc/apache2/apache2.confd:

  ```
  ServerName localhost
  ```
- replace run user in /etc/apache2/envvars

  ```
  export APACHE_RUN_USER=joe   
  export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=joe
  ```
- rewrite mode

  ```
  sudo a2enmod rewrite
  ```

### MYSQL

```
    apt-get install mysql-server  
    apt-get install mysql-client
    apt-get install mysql-workbench     
    mysql_secure_installation
```

### PHP5

```
    apt-get install php5  
    apt-cache search php  
    apt-get install php5-curl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap  
    apt-get install php5-mcrypt libssh2-php php5-dev php5-gd php5-mcrypt
```

- changed values in php.ini

  ```
  realpath_cache_ttl = 36000  
  max_execution_time = 300  
  max_input_time = 60
  memory_limit = 256M  
  post_max_size = 128M  
  upload_max_filesize = 256M  
  default_socket_timeout = 60
  ```
- ```
  apt-get install phpmyadmin
  ```
- complete manually some missing conf in: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

  ```
  include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
  ```
- virtual host test-me

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>  
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  
  ServerName test.me  
  ServerAlias *.test.me  
  DocumentRoot /home/joe/Workarea/test-me  
  <Directory "/home/joe/Workarea/test-me">  
  Options All  
  AllowOverride All  
  Require all granted  
   </Directory>  
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- in /etc/hosts

  ```
  127.0.0.1   test.me
  ```

**DRUPAL**

- created a db test-me with collation `utf8_unicode_ci`
- in: /home/joe/Workarea

  ```
  wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.28.tar.gz 
  tar xzvf drupal-7.28 
  mv drupal-7.28 test-me
  ```
- in settings.php file:

  ```
  $databases['default']['default'] = array(  
    'driver' => 'mysql', 
    'database' => 'test-me', 
    'username' => 'root', 
    'password' => '', 
    'host' => 'localhost', 
    'prefix' => 'main_', 
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 
  );
  ```
- Permissions:

  ```
  chmod 644 settings.php  
  chmod  a+w sites/default
  ```

Comment: Check your server error logs, perhaps an error with extracting or writing to the filesystem there.

Comment: Please add following lines at the start of your settings.php this will display errors on the page. error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); Also visit https://drupal.org/node/158043.

Comment: Nothing. checked all the logs and there is no trace of error. Debugging i see the code stopping while reading a property ($this->_compress_type == 'gz'). Something is happening at lower level.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install gzip` to ensure gzip is available.

Comment: nothing to do. I've added a description of the followed steps for reference.

Comment: Have you tried to install PHP 5.3?

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.5.14 on Arch Linux without problems. Drupal 7 core runs great on 5.5 and I haven't come across contrib modules that break because of the PHP version. If I were you, I'd look somewhere else.

Comment: This might not be the suggestion you are looking for, but did you try to use drush instead of the UI to en modules? might want to increase memory_limit and max_execution_time in drush.ini. Same place you can safely display/show all errors

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug, see:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1315888
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53829

As I had the same error and after deep diving I reached to `modules/system/system.tar.inc at line 716` which calls `gzopen()`. Here the errors are suppressed using `@`.

Actually its giving following error on ubuntu 14.04:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen() in /var/www/html/drupcom/modules/system/system.tar.inc on line 718
```

So this is issue with Zlib. 
I've tried to solve it using 
[these instructions](http://www.namhuy.net/2430/install-enable-zlib-linux-server.html), but no luck. Then I found that it is known bug.

Comment: I've found this [fix](https://www.drupal.org/node/2281195#comment-9109483) for core. It is bad, but it is work.

Comment: I've solved the problem after installation of [newer PHP version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1/109544#109544)

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling error reporting of PHP on your application adding temporally on the index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

You could do the same by editing the same values on the php.ini.

Enable error reporting on Drupal adding on the settings.php:

```
$conf['error_level'] = 2;
```

I had a similar problem with Drupal 6 and PHP 5.4, here is one of the reported issues related to [that problem](https://www.drupal.org/node/1954296).

Answer (score 0):

- does `phpinfo();` from the console work?
- You are aware of Apache 2.4 changes listed here:
  https://www.linode.com/docs/security/upgrading/updating-virtual-host-settings-from-apache-2-2-to-apache-2-4

I migrated from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS when 14.04.1 was released and 0 issues after examining the Apache configuration changes.

**EDIT:**

from my linked apache 2.4 changes, you're vhost entry **MUST** be named *test-me.conf* btw.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Lazy Dubuntu shell script.

> A shell script that will set-up your Drupal Dev Environment in your Ubuntu OS.

[Lazy Dubuntu Project](http://lazydubuntu.com/)

[Github - Lazy Dubuntu](https://github.com/darol100/lazydubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It is [PHP bug](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116076/how-to-install-drupal-7-on-ubuntu/138094#138094) with Zlib gzopen() function for Ubuntu32.

I've solved the problem after installation of [newer PHP version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1/109544#109544)