# Error 500 when downloading updates for modules

Tags: updating

Recently I've transferred several Drupal sites to [DigitalOcean.com](http://DigitalOcean.com) VPS server (Ubuntu).
Almost all work well.

But when I try to downloading updates for modules I get error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?render=overlay&id=82&op=do StatusText: Internal Server Error ResponseText
```

I see the error for every Drupal sites at VPS.
I can successfully update modules by drush.
But I want to understand the problem.

There is no error record at error.log (Apache)
And there is following line at access.log:

```
POST /batch?render=overlay&id=83&op=do HTTP/1.1" 500
```

How can I solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**
It seems the problem in PHP.
There is [known bug](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116076/how-to-install-drupal-7-on-ubuntu/138094#138094) with gzopen() for Ubuntu32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [PHP bug](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116076/how-to-install-drupal-7-on-ubuntu/138094#138094) with Ubuntu 32bit.

I've solved the problem after installation of [newer PHP version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1/109544#109544)